# not listing entire directory

Tags: python, listdir

Im new on Python, Im actually on a short course this week, but I have a very specific request and I dont know how to deal with it right now: I have many different txt files in a folder, when I use the following code I receive only the filename of two of the many files, why is this?
regards!

```
import dircache
lista = dircache.listdir('C:\FDF')
i = 0
check = len(lista[0])
temp = []
count = len(lista)
while count != 0:
if len(lista[i]) != check:
    temp.append(lista[i- 1])
    check = len(lista[i])
else:
    i = i + 1
count = count - 1
print (temp)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. It's kinda important in Python, you know!

Comment: First, I think you should be more explicit.

Second, you should use the methods from the os module like walk, listdir etc

Comment: The direct answer to your question is that you're only printing a list of file names that pass a particular test, having something to do with the length of the file name being different from the length of the following file name in the list.  I'm having a very hard time understanding the *intention* of the code.  What output were you expecting?  The entire list of files?  If so, why the checks on the file name lengths?

Comment: Note that `dircache` has been deprecated; you may just want to use `os.listdir()` directly instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correct, you would like to get all files?

Try it in this case:

```
import os

filesList = None
dir = 'C:\FDF'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    filesList = files
    break
print(filesList)
```

If need full path use:

```
import os.path

filesList = None
dir = 'C:\FDF'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for file in files:
        filesList.append(os.path.join(root, file))
print(filesList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the glob library: http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

It seems that it works UNIX-like for listing files so maybe it can work with this?

```
import glob

directory = 'yourdirectory/'
filelist = glob.glob(directory+'*.txt')
```